# Pass context for node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, ecmascript-6, bind

I use the following code which works partially since there are cases that the content are not passed.

```
var app = require('buildersApps');
app.addContent({
    folderPath: __dirname + '/content/'
});
app.start();
```

To solve it (the context) I add the following with the **bind()** method
which works but my question is whether there is a better/cleaner way to do it?

```
var app = require('buildersApps');
app.addContent({
    folderPath: __dirname + '/content/'
}).then(app.start.bind(app));
```

Comment: It seems your solution has nothing to do with `bind` but rather the use of  `then` (on the promise that `addContent` returns)

Comment: More idiomatic ES6 would be `.then(x => app.start(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you could use anonymous function like this

```
var app = require('buildersApps');
app.addContent({
    folderPath: __dirname + '/content/'
}).then(() => {
    app.start();
});
```

it's in fact a common pattern.